# Issue with cmake-language-server LSP when working with CMake files

Tags: plugins, lua, neovim, language-server-protocol

I recently finished configuring my neovim environment, mainly for working with python/c/cpp projects, I even managed to configure a dap setup which "kind of" works I guess. My problem is when it comes to syntax highlighting/general usage of the LSP client for CMake, nothing seems to work even though I configured it exactly the same way as other LSPs I'm currently using.

My neovim version is: NVIM v0.8.1 I installed the server using the Mason plugin. The server is correctly installed and appears in :LspInfo but is never attached to any buffer I create.

I created a project with multiple folders including a .git and build folders, which should be triggered as the root dir so the LSP should be attached to the CMakelists.txt file or Makefile file, or at least that's what I understood in the https://github.com/regen100/cmake-language-server description.

My LSP configuration is the same as this one: https://github.com/LunarVim/nvim-basic-ide/blob/master/lua/user/lsp/mason.lua adding to the servers the CMake one. I can provide some more screenshots showing other LSP clients working fine out of the box with their buffers but the CMake being active and not attaching to any CMake file I create.

[image: LSP client not attached]

The server is correctly installed and in path with Mason plugin:
[image: The server is correctly installed and in path with Mason plugin]

Do you guys have any idea why am I having this issue? Needless to say I'm a total beginner when it comes to vim/neovim stuff, and I recently managed to put together kind of a semi-decent configuration copying plenty of the options Chris and other developers from lunarvim shared in their repos.

I tried creating multiple CMake and Make style files. Plus adding more folder so that the root directory would be detected and the LSP client could be attached to the buffer successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Would you be able to provide a screenshot of a smallr screen with less empty space for your "lsp client not attached" screenshot?

Comment: Yes, a version of your first screenshot with less blank space achieved by screenshotting a sized-down window would be great. It will waste less space in the post, and will likely make the text size up larger when filling the space to make the text in the screenshot easier to read.

Comment: In the image above the filename in the tab is `CMakelist.txt` (lowercase-L) when it should be uppercase. Maybe that is why the file isn't recognized as a CMake file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @starball I decided to see if I somehow could modify the filetypes requirements for the `cmake client`. It seems like there are multiple ways of achieving that, for the record the first one is more for a more general neovim configuration search for `config.filetypes` [link](https://github.com/kabouzeid/nvim-lspinstall/wiki).

And for my specific setup I did the following:

1. Add a `cmake.lua` file under the path `/lua/user/lsp/settings/`
2. Configure the desired CMake `filetypes`
   [image: Configuration used]

Result in the previously defined buffer, as well as some other `.cmake` files:

[image: LSP Client successfully attached to buffers]

Comment: Nice work! Could you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: May I know what command to use to get the last screen output?

Comment: In command mode on neovim, simply input `LspInfo` and a similar window should pop up

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the lsp client only attaches to files ending in `.cmake` instead of `.txt`.

The change to the file type solved the issue of the attachment

Comment: Hi @starball sorry for the delay in the response. I created a bug report in the official lspconfig repository https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/issues/2406. The only answer I received was to change the file termination to ".cmake". I completelly agree with you in the sense that they should contemplate the parsing of CMakelists.txt as a trigger for the client. I will try to open a new ticket with the suggestion, regarding the screenshot from before do you still need it?

Comment: The tool author just recommended to rename the file extension from .txt to .cmake. That's not even valid as a workaround in some important cases. I commented there. Hopefully the tool author realizes their tool should change to support files named CMakeLists.txt.